# Es correcto armar un carousel modal en Javascript en vez de en html?

Tags: javascript, css

El problema que estoy teniendo, ademas de que no puedo diseñar un carusel modal decente, es que cuando hago clic sobre una imagen siempre que se abre el carousel, se muestra la primera imagen.

Por ejemplo, si tengo 10 imagenes, si hago click sobre la 5ta, se abre la primera, y tengo que ir arrastrandome hasta la deseada.

Por otro lado, estoy teniendo un grave problema, que es que estoy creando un carousel modal por cada imagen, es decir, voy a tener 10 carousel modal y encima cuando quiero cerrarlo, lo estoy eliminando, porque si lo escondo, se sobrepone el primero sobre el segundo.

Basicamente estoy haciendo todo mal y ahora la idea que se me ocurrio es crear el carousel modal desde Javascript.

Esto es lo que estoy armando ahora (pero no funciona)

```
function ModalCarousel(entrega) {
    let modal = document.createElement('div')
        modal.setAttribute('class', 'modal')
        modal.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')
        modal.setAttribute('id', 'myModal')

    let modalDialog = document.createElement('div')
        modalDialog.setAttribute('class', 'modal-dialog')
        modalDialog.setAttribute('id', 'modalDialog')

    let modalContent = document.createElement('div')
        modalContent.setAttribute('class', 'modal-content')

    let modalHeader = document.createElement('div')
        modalHeader.setAttribute('class', 'modal-header')
        modalHeader.setAttribute('id', 'modalHeader')

    let btnClose = document.createElement('button')
        btnClose.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        btnClose.setAttribute('class', 'btn-close')
        btnClose.setAttribute('id', 'btnClose')
        btnClose.setAttribute('onclick', 'CloseModal()')
        btnClose.setAttribute('data-bs-dismiss', 'modal')
        btnClose.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Close')    

    let modalBody = document.createElement('div')
        modalBody.setAttribute('class', 'modal-body')
        modalBody.setAttribute('data-bs-interval', 'false')
        modalBody.setAttribute('id', entrega)

    let carousel = document.createElement('div')
        carousel.setAttribute('id', 'C_' + entrega)
        carousel.setAttribute('class', 'carousel slide carousel-dark')
        carousel.setAttribute('data-bs-interval', 'false')

    let innerCarousel = document.createElement('div')
        innerCarousel.setAttribute('id', 'Entrega_' + entrega)
        innerCarousel.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-inner')
        innerCarousel.setAttribute('data-bs-interval', 'false')

    let buttonPrev = document.createElement('button')
        buttonPrev.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-control-prev')
        buttonPrev.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        buttonPrev.setAttribute('data-bs-target', '#C_' + entrega)
        buttonPrev.setAttribute('data-bs-slide', 'prev')

    let spanPrev1 = document.createElement('span')
        spanPrev1.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-control-prev-icon')
        spanPrev1.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')

    let spanPrev2 = document.createElement('span')
        spanPrev2.setAttribute('class', 'visually-hidden')
        spanPrev2.textContent = 'Previous'

    let buttonNext = document.createElement('button')
        buttonNext.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-control-next')
        buttonNext.setAttribute('type', 'button')
        buttonNext.setAttribute('data-bs-target', '#C_' + entrega)
        buttonNext.setAttribute('data-bs-slide', 'next')

    let spanNext1 = document.createElement('span')
        spanNext1.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-control-next-icon')
        spanNext1.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')

    let spanNext2 = document.createElement('span')
        spanNext2.setAttribute('class', 'visually-hidden')
        spanNext2.textContent = 'Next'

    buttonPrev.appendChild(spanPrev1)
    buttonPrev.appendChild(spanPrev2)
    buttonNext.appendChild(spanNext1)
    buttonNext.appendChild(spanNext2)

    innerCarousel.appendChild(buttonPrev)
    innerCarousel.appendChild(buttonNext)

    carousel.appendChild(innerCarousel)

    modalBody.appendChild(carousel)

    modalHeader.appendChild(btnClose)

    modalContent.appendChild(modalHeader)
    modalContent.appendChild(modalBody)

    modalDialog.appendChild(modalContent)
    modal.appendChild(modalDialog)

    let z = 0;
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "GetPedidoImagenes",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'entrega': entrega },
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("Longitud: " + result.length);
            if (result == 0) {
                alert("No hay Imagenes");
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
                while (z < result.length) {
                    let carusel = innerCarousel;
                    if (z == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        //img.setAttribute('src', srcImg)
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                }
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
}


function CloseModal() {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.remove();
}
```

Queria saber las opiniones de ustedes que saben muchisimo mas, yo soy muy nuevo con ésto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo?
Estoy creando un `carousel modal` y con un `AJAX` me traigo una lista de los directorios de imágenes, las cuales las utilizo para mostrar en el `carousel modal`.

Problemas:

1. El `AJAX` funciona perfecto, me trae las imagenes, pero el problema es que si tengo 10 imagenes, y quiero abrir la quinta, siempre se me va a abrir la primera imagen, teniendo que arrastrarme siempre para la derecha hasta llegar a la que quiero.
2. No puedo darle estilos al `modal carousel`. Utilizo la librerías de `Bootstrap 5` pero igual así aunque utilice las clases correctas o mínimamente las que se muestran en los ejemplos (`d-block` y `w-100`), el modal siempre se va a ver mas grande que la pantalla, aunque con `css` utilice `vh` y `vw`. (Como se ve en la foto, estoy limitando el `height` pero tambien se limita el `width` aunque yo no le haya dado ninguna limitacion)

ésta es una imagen de prueba, dejo el html..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/images/991198_80926607_0044-00028806_2022-09-22_11-14-49.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/images/991198_80926607_0044-00028806_2022-09-22_11-14-56.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/images/991198_80926607_0044-00028806_2022-09-22_11-15-01.jpg" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega una variable, cuando abres el primer modal, IsModalOpened, en el primer click pones true y ya para el segundo sabes que ya esta abierto, falso para cuando ya cierras,

Comment: Claro, pero es no es buena practica hacerlo todo con Js, no?

Comment: Es posible, ahora si es buena idea? Quizás en algunos casos. Lo que sí veo un problema en tu código, entiendo que empleas bootsrap, esta librería crea eventos a las modales y a al carrusel, esta creación de eventos se realiza cuando carga la página, por lo que tu deberás crearlos manualmente, en la documentación de cada componente esto lo pone al final (para que lo mires). Por otro lado tienen un AJAX ahí que no se entiende, quizás si explicas que quieres lograr alguien podría darte una solución menos complicada.